# Is it possible to bridge MQTT broker mosquitto to Cloud PubSub?

Tags: mqtt, google-cloud-pubsub, mosquitto, google-cloud-iot

I have a local mosquitto broker that I would like to connect to Google Cloud pubsub queue.
I looked into Google Cloud IOT core but with no luck, I cannot seem to connect to it

Here is my mosquitto configuration

```
#
# A full description of the configuration file is at
# /usr/share/doc/mosquitto/examples/mosquitto.conf.example

pid_file /var/run/mosquitto.pid

persistence true
persistence_location /var/lib/mosquitto/


# Goolge IoT Core Configuration

connection bridge-to-gcp

address mqtt.googleapis.com:8883

bridge_attempt_unsubscribe false
bridge_certfile /Downloads/rsa_cert.pem
bridge_keyfile /Downloads/rsa_private.pem
bridge_cafile /Downloads/roots.pem
bridge_protocol_version mqttv311
bridge_insecure false

tls_version tlsv1.2
try_private true

start_type automatic
cleansession true
notifications false

local_clientid local-to-remote-gcp-bridge

remote_clientid projects/toolsense-dev/locations/europe-west1/registries/test-registry/devices/test-device

topic # both
```

Is there a way to forward all the messages received from edge devices to Google Cloud Pubsub?

Comment: [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/63561428/edit) the question to show the log output of it trying to connect.

Comment: Hey Ahmed Etefy, is https://cloud.google.com/iot/docs/how-tos/mqtt-bridge the tutorial that you follow through? What kind of errors did you see from your end? Would you mind to update your question?

Answer (score 0):

After deeper research, it is not possible without the existence of a gateway device either virtually or physically. It could even be client code running on same machine as the one running the broker.

This usecase is however possible in AWS Iot
https://wiki.seeedstudio.com/Arduino-AWS-IOT-Bridge/

Answer (score 0):

As of Oct 2023, there is now a GCP (not official but well maintained and part of their repo) [MQTT <-> Cloud Pub/Sub connector](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/mqtt-cloud-pubsub-connector).

> This architecture is aimed at connecting MQTT brokers to Cloud Pub/Sub.

[image]